# Is there any way to write special association?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table which named `movies` and it has `genres` column. In `genres` column, I store the movie's genres id like `[0,5,10]` type. Those are foreign keys but stored in different way. Is there any way to use those foreign keys with EF.

I want to use it like `List<genres> x = movie.genres`.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use a regular Many To Many relationship.  Why do you want to store a list in a single column?

Comment: I thought that, store the genres id like this way can be more efficient. I don't know Is it the best or worst way. :) And I am wondering can I write special association for that?

Answer (score 0):

"*I thought that, store the genres id like this way can be more efficient.*"

Nope. Keep it simple and let the tools (EF and Database) do what they do. The efficiency is already built there, no need to try reinventing something. Start with the simplest, most standard thing, then look at alternatives to address concerns as those concerns are proven to be valid.

As far as EF is concerned, your Movies can reference a collection of Genres, and your Genre can optionally reference a collection of Movies. With the inclusion of a MovieGenre table containing just a composite key consisting of a MovieId and GenreId, EF can map this relationship automatically without needing to define a MovieGenres entity.

So for entities like:

```
[Table("Movies")]
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; private set; } = new List<Genre>();
}

[Table("Genres")]
public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; private set; } = new List<Movie>();
}
```

Then in the OnModelCreating (or using entity type configuration):

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Genres)
            .WithMany(x => x.Movies)
            .Map(x => x.ToTable("MovieGenres").MapLeftKey("MovieId").MapRightKey("GenreId"));
```

When you go to send Movies to a UI or out via an API for instance and you can flatten genre information as you see fit. For instance to display movies released in a date range with their genres:

```
var movies = context.Movies
    .Where(x => x.ReleaseDate >= startDate && x.ReleaseDate <= endDate)
    .Select(x => new MovieViewModel
    {
        MovieId = x.MovieId,
        Name = x.Name,
        Genres = x.Genres.Select(g => new GenreViewModel {GenreId = g.GenreId, Name = g.Name).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

If you're expecting a large list of movies and the UI might display the genre name, but you don't want to transmit copies of the genre for each and every movie:

```
// get genres for the applicable movies
var genres = context.Movies
    .Where(x => x.ReleaseDate >= startDate && x.ReleaseDate <= endDate)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Genres)
    .Distinct(new GenreEqualityComparer())
    .Select(x => new GenreViewModel{ GenreId = x.GenreId, Name = x.Name})
    .ToList();
// Get the movies with their Genre IDs.
var movies = context.Movies
    .Where(x => x.ReleaseDate >= startDate && x.ReleaseDate <= endDate)
    .Select(x => new MovieViewModel
    {
        MovieId = x.MovieId,
        Name = x.Name,
        GenreIds = x.Genres.Select(g => g.GenreId).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

From here, the UI/Consumer will know what they need about the Genres, and can associate the movies to their Genre by ID without the excess payload of repeated genre information for each movie record. Again, this may not be necessary, but in cases where you might be selecting a lot of references to a relative few and/or large pieces of data you have the option to do something like above.

Comment: First of all Thank you the very clear answer. But there is a misunderstanding because of my comment. I am really sorry because I did not explain it more. Actually, I use the `Genres` for [Apriori Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) and _storing the `Genres` like that way is more efficient for this(apriori)_. When I started to create UI for this project, I just wondered the my main question.